# Animating a UIButton on a custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I have a custom view on which I have a `UIButton`. I am trying to do a simple animation in which the button should get half in size within a second of pressing the button.

However the problem is that button is not animating I have checked the action method and it is being called but the buttons are not being animated.

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
if (self=[super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    //Loading From Nib
    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SelectionMenu" owner:nil options:nil];
    [self addSubview:views[0]];
}
return self;
}

- (IBAction)firstBtn:(id)sender {
//Disabling the other two buttons
self.upperBtn2.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.upperBtn3.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.slider setHidden:NO];
[self.slider.layer setZPosition:9.0];
[self startAnimation];
self.upperBtn2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.upperBtn3.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

-(void)startAnimation
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    [self.upperBtn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 100)];
}];
}
```

What is wrong here.

Comment: Does `firstBtn` calls on `touchUpInside:`? If so reset it to `touchDown`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your startAnimation with this,

```
- (void)startAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.upperBtn1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     self.btn.frame = CGRectMake(self.btn.frame.origin.x,self.btn.frame.origin.y,50,50);
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```